# How does foo(&nil) behave differently than foo(&"not a proc")?

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, null

I found out from heckle that

```
[1, 2, 3].each(&nil)
```

doesn't cause any errors - it just returns an enumerator.

By contrast,

```
[1, 2, 3].each(&"")
```

raises

```
TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Proc)
```

Also, `&nil` causes block_given? to return false

```
def block_given_tester
  if block_given?
    puts "Block given"
  else
    puts "Block not given"
  end
end

block_given_tester(&nil) # => Block not given
```

It's not because `NilClass` implements `to_proc` - I checked the RDoc.

I can understand *why* it'd be nice to have `&nil`, but I'm not sure *how* it's done. Is this just one of the ways `nil` has special behavior not shared by other objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer can be found by looking at Ruby's source code.

Ruby 1.8:

Look at the function `block_pass` in the file `eval.c`. Note that it treats `nil` specially from `Proc` objects (the macro `NIL_P`). If the function is passed a nil value, it evaluates an empty block (I think) and returns. The code right after it checks whether the object is a `Proc` object (the function `rb_obj_is_proc`) and raises the exception "wrong argument type (expected Proc)" if it isn't.

Ruby 1.9.2:

Look at the method `caller_setup_args` in the file `vm_insnhelper.c`. It converts the proc with `to_proc` only
if it is not nil; otherwise, the type conversion and type check are bypassed.

Comment: I assume you're looking at one of the 1.8 branches not one of the 1.9 branches.

Comment: Yes, that's from Ruby 1.8, as it's the code I have available.  I'm now downloading the code for Ruby 1.9.2 to see if anything has changed.